render a 360 animation with gpu on Mac Studio
im trying ro render an animation for VR (camera equirectangular) on a Mac studio,before I used the CpU it was rendering but really slowly (35 days for 250 frames) so I changed the scene to device GPU Compute and since then it render for just a few second and after it crashes so I don't knew what to do !!!
I also used the correct size ratio 2:1 for vr, and I already tried to go in edit>preference>system>Cycles Render Devices> metal> Apple M2 Max (GPU-30cores)
file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vd6eZP3CDuwMenOqX8Uh0TgYie2SLzLh/view?usp=sharing

if u want a realistic estimation of the render, you should pack all resources and upload that file. thx.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vd6eZP3CDuwMenOqX8Uh0TgYie2SLzLh/view?usp=sharing

uhm...i am sorry to say, but you have a ridiculous amount of pixels here: [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/VaBR4Yth.png -> so just one frame has more than 643 Mio pixels....is that really what you wanna have?

hi I just followed one of the instructions in a tutorial regarding VR and 360 Video. I could lower the number of pixels but on the other hand when I try to do other videos, the VR outcomes are pixelated. Can you help me identify the average of minimum quantify of pixels in order to have a good outcome with nice definition ? Thanks for your help :)

pls add the link to that tutorial you followed - i am really curious. I would take the absolute minimum (same) resolution as the VR has. No pixel more. Because every pixel more make the render slower.

Perhaps you didn't notice, but while you set a resolution of 8192x4096, you also set a factor of 400%, which means your actual rendered resolution is 32768x16384. It is more than 16 times bigger than Youtube's maximum supported resolution of 8k, most people don't pay the premium subscription to be able to see that much, and i bet more than half the people's graphics card can't even decode such a big resolution to begin with.
According to VRcompare - The Internet's Largest VR & AR Headset Database, the biggest VR headsets resolutions are 3840x2160 per-eye. A guesstimate of the common resolution in the current pool of popular headsets is more in the lines of 1800x2000.
I think it is very interesting to read this article from Meta Quest for Creators:
While you could in theory use 8192x4096 resolution in the Meta Quest 2, it is only the maximum supported resolution for a flat video shown on a virtual flat screen. Not for a 360 or 180 video viewed in perspective (what the above article calls "immersive video format").
For a 360-degree video, the minimum and maximum recommended resolutions are only 3840x1920 and 7200x3600 respectively.

In order to choose a resolution, I think you should first ask a question: what is your target? If you target a specific VR headset or a small group, then seek for that headset's specifications and use the supported and recommended resolution.
If you aim for a large audience, then pick an average resolution anyone should be able to enjoy. That means, not too low for good looks, but also not too high to not risk some hardware refusing to read that video or it being too heavy and slow to download and read.
